# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append' - FastAPI + SQLalchemy - many to many relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, relationship, fastapi

I'm trying to create a Many2Many relationship, but I get an error when I try to write data.

Models

```
companies_users = Table(
    'companies_users',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('user_id', ForeignKey('users.id')),
    Column('company_id', ForeignKey('companies.id')),
    Column('is_active_owner', Boolean),
    Column('is_active_user', Boolean)
)



class DbUser(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    bio = Column(String, default=None, nullable=True)
    time_created = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    time_updated = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())
    users_companies = relationship(
        'DbCompany', secondary=companies_users, backref='companies_users'
    )
    company_administrators = relationship('DbCompany', secondary=companies_administrators)


users = DbUser.__table__


class DbCompany(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'companies'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    description = Column(String, nullable=False)
    is_hide = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
    owner = Column(String, ForeignKey('users.email'))


companies = DbCompany.__table__
```

Function

```
async def add_user_to_company_a(self, company_id: int, user_id: int, current_user: UserDisplayWithId):
    user = await self.database.fetch_one(users.select().where(users.c.id == user_id))
    company = await self.database.fetch_one(companies.select().where(companies.c.id == company_id))
    if user is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f'User with id {user_id} not found')
    elif company is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f'Company with id {company_id} not found')
    else:
        await user.users_companies.append(company)
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                            detail=f'User {user_id} successfully added to company {company_id}')
```

There is a problem in

```
await user.users_companies.append(company)
```

I know there is no separate users_companies column in the table, but in all the manuals and documentation I've seen only this option.

I tried to use back_populates, but it had the same result. Double-checked all imports and validations - everything works.

Can you tell me what may be the problem? Is there some other way for asynchronous execution?

Comment: Have you looked at what value `user` actually has before you attempt to use `append` on a relationship? It seems like you're attempting to use the objects as ORM objects, but are using plain table querying?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use the databases library to connect to the db and through tables. I have a class in models and I take a table from it: users = DbUser.__table__

Comment: I'm guessing that's the reason, since you're attempting to use ORM functionality (i.e. defining relationships and adding ORM-based objects to them) without using the ORM part of SQLAlchemy.

Comment: I'm using Databases which based on SQLalchemy and use the same queries. I may be wrong, but other queries work

Comment: Yes, but SQLAlchemy has two parts - one is the core features (which `databases` use afaict), the other is the ORM module: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/14/orm/ . The `relationship` definition is part of the ORM module: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/14/orm/relationships.html - so I'm guessing `databases` doesn't support the ORM part (they note that they support core), and that's why you're having issues. The ORM module returns larger objects that where the relationships gets hydrated/lazyloaded as they are accessed (or through a join on load).